# Temporary EditText and keyboard on bottom of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create EditText on bottom of screen and open keyboard (then this EditText will move above keyboard with RelativeLayout + ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM), it works fine with SetContentView but with addContentView the RelativeLayout + ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM doesn't work for me and the keyboard overlap the EditText.

In some way I want to generate this temporary EditText independently the layout being displayed on screen, so If I press any button on any layout I call this function to create a temporary EditText on bottom of screen and bring the keyboard.

I can't change the whole main layout because this layout is generated by Unity3D. I need a way to generate this EditText and act independently the layout is being displayed on screen.

My code:

```
public void openInput()
{
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
                EditText inputName = new EditText(context);
                inputName.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                inputName.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(40)} );

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams editTextParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(600, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                editTextParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                editTextParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

                RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(context);
                relativeLayout.addView(inputName, editTextParams);

                addContentView(relativeLayout, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

                inputName.requestFocus();
                InputMethodManager msg = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                msg.showSoftInput(inputName, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        });
}
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

put your whole layout in a scroll view, (as your set contentview)

and then when you do addContentView the layout will scroll up to the focused view, rather than push the view up

Comment: I can't put the whole layout in scroll view because the main layout is generated by Unity3D. I need a way to embed this EditText and act independently the layout being displayed on screen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a pop-up dialog window to edit long list of parameters one by one. That's also helps to add more helpful information on the parameter being edited, like instructions, hints, etc...